# Can You Create Your Own Cosms in Torg?

Tags: homebrew, torg

Torg has a number of really cool cosms described in the books: the Cyberpapacy, Aysle, Nippon Tech, Orrorsh, etc. These are rather detailed and are said to each inhabit a certain part of the Earth. In general, the development of these cosms, and the entire Possibility Wars, are developed via metaplot rather than developed with each individual game table.

Because of these strictly defined rules for cosms, I'm wondering: does Torg allow for GMs to create additional cosms in the setting? Obviously a GM can just houserule one in, but I didn't know if there was anything in the official rules designated to allow for this (perhaps some area of the world that was in constant flux i.e. it's whatever you want). If so, are there any rules for doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only limited advice for developing new cosms for Torg. The axiom scale is presented in the core rules; it's not quite well enough developed to really make the task anything less than "creator fiat" for what the cosm is and does. Once you know what the cosm is, one can find relative values, and thus know what's going to cause reality issues (disconnection, especially) from or in the other cosms.

I've never seen any more concrete advice than that section.

In its heyday, some home-brewed cosms did surface on WWIVnet and Fidonet. The axioms didn't seem too out of line at the time, but I don't have the files anymore, and so can't really compare them.

Answer (score 3):

Never let a systems lack of rules for something get in the way of a good story. The rules are there to enable you, not constrain you.

Looking at the maps, a relatively small portion of the Earths surface has been conquered by the Possibility Raiders, so there is absolutely no reason why you couldn't create a new High Lord, who comes to earth and starts carving out his or her own cosm on Earth. The Worldbook contains lots of information about Cosms and how they came to be, so I would use those descriptions as the starting point for your own cosm.

Alternatively, you could go in a different direction. You could have the player characters come across the Earth Cosms Darkness Device and have them go taking Core Earths axioms on a rampage through a variety of other cosms. Remember every realm conquered brings possibilities back to Earth which can be used to fight off the invaders.

You could even have them break the Darkness Device the first time they use it and then have them go on a cosm hopping campaign trying to find their way home.